# Is it possible to use selenium to extract data from an API call respone?

Tags: python, json, xml, selenium-webdriver

I have extracted data from an web site by selenium in Python very easily. However, I have been asked to extract the same data by API call. The API call is working fine. But to extract the required data from the API response by converting it into a JSON object seems bit tedious. I had to write lot of nested loops which was very straight forward when I was using selenium. Is there anyway selenium can be applied on an API response. If yes, if anyone can share some example or a link where I can find some example it will be great.

Comment: Rather than selenium, have you tried simply using the requests package?

Comment: as far as i know selenium is used to interact with UI in the page, not for api calls.

Comment: You should use a html or xml  parser depends on the request format.

Comment: I am using XML or HTML parser and converting it into json object to get the desired data. But it is not that straight forward like selenium. Hence wondering if there is any way after retrieving the XML from API call if it is possible to use selenium